# Why can't my Django view receive data from a created tag in my Django template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django-templates, django-views

Django view:

```
  if request.method == 'POST':
      myData = request.POST.get('tester', None)
      print myData
```

Django template (jquery and javascript):

```
  var i = document.createElement('input');
  i.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  i.setAttribute('id', 'tester');
  i.setAttribute('name','tester');
  i.setAttribute('value', 'PLEASE GET THIS!');
  $('#tester').appendTo('body');
  $('#add_here').before(i);
```

I have no issue getting the value from an  tag that is hardcoded into the template file but I am having a problem getting the value from an  tag that I have created using jQuery and javascript. Any hints?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the new input is in the form that is being submitted to the server? I can't tell from this short snippet of code.

Comment: I am not sure. What do you recommend I do to check that?

Comment: On the page DOM. If you are using chrome or firefox then you can inspect the current state of the page and confirm that the new element has been added and is in the right places.

Comment: Ok yes I have done that. The element is there.

Comment: Then that would indicate a problem on the django side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered the issue. There was a random closing /div tag in my HTML that didn't have an opening tag. I removed it and the code started working like it should. For reasons unknown to me, the random /div wasn't allowing the created elements to appear in the POST data. The elements were showing up in the right places when I did the inspect element, but when you look at the actual POST data the elements were not there.

I hope this saves someone the time it cost me. Here are some links to help you validate your HTML. These are the links I used to discover my problem.

http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input